# Error with segue: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver has no segue with identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm getting this error with my app: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ViewController: 0x17e60c10>) has no segue with identifier 'dateTimeString''`. Code is this:

ViewController.m

```
 -(IBAction) alarmSetButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd:MM:YYYY:ss:mm:hh"];
    NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateTimePicker.date ];
    NSLog( @"Alarm Set : %@", dateTimeString );


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd:MM:YYYY:ss:mm:hh"];
    NSDate *dateTimeSeconds = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateTimeSeconds = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateTimeString];
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateTimePicker.date];
    NSLog(@"seconds %.f", seconds);

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Alarm-Clock.m4a", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    _alarmPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
    [_alarmPlayer playAtTime: _alarmPlayer.deviceCurrentTime + seconds];

    NSLog( @"Alarm Set button tapped : %@", dateTimeString );

    [self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate: dateTimePicker.date];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"dateTimeStringSegue" sender: nil];
    [self presentMessage:(@"Alarm succesfully set for %@",dateTimeString)];
}

-(IBAction)alarmCancelButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog( @"Alarm Cancel button tapped");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    [self presentMessage:@"Alarm Canceled Lazy Pants!"];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ViewController3 *tvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"dateTimeStringSegue"])
    {
        tvc.dateTimeString = (@"%@",_dateTimeString);
        NSLog(@"Segue");
    }
}
```

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateTimePicker;
}

@property NSInteger numberOfLoops;
@property(readonly) NSTimeInterval deviceCurrentTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *alarmPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dateTimeString;


- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:dateTimePicker;

-(void) presentMessage: (NSString *) message;
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate: (NSDate *) fireDate;
-(IBAction) alarmSetButtonTapped:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) alarmCancelButtonTapped:(id)sender;
- (BOOL)playAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time;

@end
```

SegueDestination.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController3 : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger tapCount;
@property NSInteger numberOfLoops;
@property(readonly) NSTimeInterval deviceCurrentTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *alarmPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dateTimeString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateTimePicker;

- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:dateTimePicker;
- (BOOL)playAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time;

- (IBAction)iconsBtn:(id)sender;


@end
```

SegueDestination.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController3 ()
{
    AVAudioPlayer *_alarmPlayer;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController3

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wwv5.jpg"]];


}

- (void) buttonTouchDownRepeat:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if(touch.tapCount == 3) {
        NSLog(@"Twice");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"UGHHHHH");
}

- (IBAction)iconsBtn:(id)sender {

}
```

I'm trying to access the `dateTimeString` in my `2nd ViewController` but whenever I click the button that is supposed to send it my app terminates with that error. This is the first time I've attempted to use segue and I'm not going so great with it. Once this error is sorted will I be able to call `dateTimeString`in the `2nd ViewController`and get the value set in the `1st ViewController`?

Thanks!

Edit: I have already done the identifier in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard you need to set Identifier for your segue:

[image]

Comment: In the code I've noticed that you're calling [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"dateTimeStringSegue" sender: nil]; while the error is about 'dateTimeString' segue. Are you sure your code is in sync with the storyboard?

Comment: In the prepareForSeque in the 1st view controller,  what value is displayed for  `[segue identifier]` in the NSLog?